# Stream API Java удаление и обновление элемента в коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции, java-stream, обновление, удаление

Пробую делать задание, я только на стадии изучения API, пытаюсь сделать удаление элемента с коллекции и обновление. Есть такой класс с полями

```
public class Worker{
    private String name;
    private int id;
    private int salary;
    private String position;

//геттеры и сеттеры
}
```

Есть методы

```
public void changeSalary(String name, Integer salary) {
//Implement updating workers you see fit.
}


public void fireWorker(String name) {
//Implement deleting workers by name. 
}
```

Удаление пробовала сделать так, но оба варианта не проходят, сказали не все. Не знаю что добавить. А как сделать обновление элемента не могу придумать.

```
Collection<Worker> collection = Arrays.asList();
collection.stream().dropWhile(s -> Objects.equals(s,"Adam N"))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

/////////// другой вариант

```
Collection<Worker> collection = Arrays.asList();
collection.stream()
       .filter(str -> !Objects.equals(str,"Adam N"));
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Нужно результат стрима присвоить старой переменной: collection = collection.stream()...

Comment: Я правильно понимаю? Stream<Worker> result=collection.stream();

Comment: `collection = collection.stream().filter(...).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема в показанном коде - некорректное сравнение объектов `Worker`, которые содержатся в `Stream<Worker>` со строковой константой `"Adam N"`.

Для удаления элементов из коллекции существует метод [`Collection::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) принимающий предикат:

```java
Collection<Worker> collection = Arrays.asList();

collection.removeIf(worker -> "Adam N".equalsIgnoreCase(worker.getName()));
```

Или же следует применять предикат в `.filter`, если нужно получить копию списка без удалённого сотрудника:

```
Collection<Worker> noAdam = collection
        .stream()
        .filter(worker -> !Objects.equals("Adam N", worker.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Для обновления элемента в списке следует корректно применить `.filter`, а затем использовать `forEach`:

```java
collection
        .stream()
        .filter(worker -> Objects.equals("Eva F", worker.getName()))
        .forEach(worker -> worker.setSalary(1_000));
```